# How to get the first element matching a criteria in Crystal?

Tags: crystal-lang

I first looked for `find` as much of the API is the same as Ruby but could not find `find`. So I thought the next best would be `select` + `first` (my array is very small so this would be fine).

Looking at the Crystal API `select!` for an Array takes a block, in the same way as in Ruby. It appears `select!` mutates the receiving Array, there is no `select` (that I can see at least!).

This is my code:

```
segment = text.split(' ').select! { |segment| segment.include?("rm_") }.first
```

The error is:

```
segment = text.split(' ').select! { |segment| segment.include?("rm_") }.first
                                     ^~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both `Enumerable#find` and `Enumerable#select` exist and are documented on [Enumerable](http://crystal-lang.org/api/Enumerable.html).

Thus something like the following does work as you know it from Ruby:

```
segment = text.split(' ').find &.includes?("rm_")
```

You can also spare the intermediate array with a regular expression:

```
segment = text[/rm_[^ ]+/]
```

And if you replace `include?` with `includes?` in your sample code, it actually works too.